# Grails & SMS plugin

Tags: grails, sms

Is there any recommendation for SMS plugin which can be easily integrated with Grails?

I'm building a management system which sends customers Y/N confirmation via text message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost and deliverance quality of SMS services depends on which countries you will be sending SMS to, but (prior to changing to a Swedish vendor) we have used the international vendor Clickatell with ok results.

You don't need a Grails plugin for that, just use HTTPBuilder (e.g. by including the Grails REST plugin) with Grails to call the Clickatell API according to their documentation.

Here is some old sample code (may not be working if the API has changed):

```
    import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
    import groovyx.net.http.EncoderRegistry
    import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT

    def http = new HTTPBuilder(host)
    http.contentType = TEXT
    EncoderRegistry encoders = new EncoderRegistry();
    encoders.setCharset('ISO-8859-1')
    http.setEncoderRegistry(encoders)

    http.request(POST) {
      uri.path = 'http/sendmsg'
      requestContentType = URLENC
      body = [api_id: '1234567', user: 'john', password: 'doe', from: 'Company', to: NUMBER, text: 'Hello world', concat: '3', callback: '2', deliv_ack: '1']
      response.success = { resp, reader ->
        def msg = reader.text
        if (msg.substring(0, 2) == 'ID') {
        } else if (msg.substring(0, 3) == 'ERR') {
        } else {
        }
      }
      response.failure = { resp ->
      }
    }
```

Comment: The country is Australia. Thanks. I'll try to connect between Grails & Clickatell API.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some old sample code that might give you a head start.